# Creating custom 9 patch button with diagonal background pattern

Tags: android, button, nine-patch

I have a custom button with a diagonal background pattern, and I really going crazy to transform it in a nine patch png. I have a lot of button with different size where I should use it and the nine patch looks like it is the way.
Is it possibile? Or there is a better solution than a nine patch?

[image: Original Button]

Comment: I don't think it can be done with ninepatch, due to diagonal lines. Ninepatch has no way to repeat such patterns. You can use patterned background, but you'll lose the gloss effect and rounded corners.

Comment: Yes I am stuck with the problem you mentioned, I am looking for an alternative method. I am trying now with a custom button with a shape and the layers for the gloss effect and the bitmap for the pattern. As soon I have some result I will post it.

Comment: Post an answer to your own question if you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

After some trial and error I made it... the best way was to make a custom button with layer-list and all the elements inside it. The pattern is a bitmap and the round corner are a stroke on top of the bitmap to cover it.

The result

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ff4f565a" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="#ff002f44" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="7dp"
    android:left="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:top="7dp">
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="7dp"
            android:left="7dp"
            android:right="7dp"
            android:top="7dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:left="-1dp" android:bottom="-1dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_btn_pattern_gloss" />
</item>
<item android:top="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#ff002f44" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```